# getItemAtIndex is not a function error

Tags: javascript, xul

I have a weird problem with xul and javascript. I have tree with multiple rows of data in it. And I've to select every row that has active column set to `"NO"` and change `background color` for that entire row.

My javascript code is this:

```
function markInactive() {

    var tree = document.getElementById('bsTree');
    var treerow;

    for (var i = 0; i < tree.view.rowCount; i++) {

        if (tree.view.getCellText(i, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("bsActive")) == "NO") {

            treerow = tree.view.getItemAtIndex(i);
            treerow.firstChild.setAttribute('style', 'background: #FF0000');

        }  
    }  
}
```

Now the weird part. This doesn't work because my jsconsole is returning with error that `getItemAtIndex is not a function`. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I don't see the [tree view interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsITreeView) specifying such a method. Why do you think it should exist?

Comment: @FelixKling: It's a method of [nsITreeContentView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITreeContentView) and this is indeed the source of the problem I think.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I've tried tree.contentView but i get the same error message.

Comment: Is the data for this tree actually specified as XUL nodes inside the `<treechildren>` element? Or is it using templates or something like this? Note: regardless of this issue - styling tree rows doesn't work that way.

Comment: @WladimirPalant it's treechildren element

Comment: @anel_b: And when does your code run? Is the tree already initialized at this point?

Comment: @WladimirPalant yes it is. I've also tried to call this function when you click on tree and not on load but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by building my own custom tree view and by editing getCellProperties method of the tree

```
getCellProperties: function (row, col, props) {

    if(tree.view.getCellText(row, tree.columns.getNamedColumn("bsActive")) == "NO"){

          var aserv=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/atom-service;1"].
                    getService(Components.interfaces.nsIAtomService);

          props.AppendElement(aserv.getAtom("makeItRed"));

    }
}
```

And CSS:

```
treechildren::-moz-tree-cell(makeItRed){
     background-color: #ff0000;
}
```